# Full assets path in application.html.erb layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to use the open graph meta tags to do something like this:

```
  <meta name="og:image" content="/assets/icon.png">
```

But it seems is not loading the image.  How should I access the full path of the assets, or what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Might be browser cache. Have you tried clearing your browser cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the Asset Pipeline?

If so:

```
<meta name="og:image" content="<%= asset_path('icon.png') %>">
```